# Нужно написать регулярное выражение

Tags: python, django, регулярные-выражения, url

Есть задача: есть ссылки типа **`"http://хост/{4 любых символа}"`**.И есть другой url(например,**`"http//хост/onboarding/sign-in"`**).При запросе на оба урла отвечает одна и та же вьюха,а в моем случае мне так не нужно).Поэтому я пытался использовать регулярные выражения для первого url(**`"http://хост/{4 любых символа}"`**) Вот: **`(?P<key>.{4})$`**. Но в данном случае оно просто срезает с конца 4 символа на любых урлах и предоставляет мне их как группу. Можно ли как-то ограничить кол-во символов,используя регулярные выражения так,чтобы если ссылка будет содержать больше 4 символов после **`хост/`**,то она уже не подходит?

Comment: Пробовали добавить `/` перед группой: `/(?P<key>.{4})$`, а лучше `/(?P<key>[^/]{4})$`?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin помог второй вариант)Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderMashin, подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать про "P<key>" в регулярном выражении? убился - не нашёл... я понял, что оно делает, но как и где об этом написано, не смог найти.

Comment: Это захват в именованную группу. Почитать можно здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение

```
/(?P<key>[^/]{4})$
```